# Can initramfs be prevented from entering a recovery console?

Tags: initramfs

For some errors, initramfs will drop into a recovery console to allow the user to fix things before booting.

This can be a problem both for security (eg on a customer facing kiosk) and ability to recover the system (eg unattended systems and IOT devices)

Is there a way to reconfigure this so that it reboots instead?

I can configure grub so that it tries a different boot option if it the system doesn't reach steady state, but I can't do anything if it just sits there waiting for user input that will never come.

---

Note that, far from a system being totally unrecoverable, a failed boot can often be resolved in the boot loader by rolling back to a previously working configuration. This technique is very common in IOT.  However it might on the IOT device self-rebooting on failure.

Comment: `sudo chmod -x /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/zz-busybox-initramfs` This hook copies the busybox binary and creates the links in the initrid.

Comment: Yes I tried it out. If you are unsure you can tell update-initramfs to save the initrid to another folder like in your $HOME. `sudo update-initramfs -c -v -k $(uname -r) -b $HOME/some-created-folder`

Comment: @nobody if you think it's valid maybe post it as an answer and let folks vote on it. I'm pretty skeptical because what you're describing is removing the whole shell from initramfs and that's needed to run the shell scripts which are the entire purpose of initramfs.

Comment: Before I test another idea, I would like to ask, is this a (U)EFI system ?

Comment: @Marco  Yes, but it's booting via grub, not the EFI kernel stub. That has to be as it is: I need grub so that I can detect a reboot cycle and fall back to an old configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the initramfs debug shell and reboot immediately with the kernel argument `panic=<seconds>` eg: `panic=10`.

From [man initramfs-tools](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man7/initramfs-tools.7.html)

> panic sets an timeout on  panic.   panic=sec  is  a  documented  security  feature:  it disables the debug shell.

**Warning**

Don't use `panic=0`. This does the opposite and disables the reboot feature instead of enabling it. initramfs follows the same semantics as the Kernel.

From the [kernel admin guide](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v6.4/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html):

> ```
> panic=          [KNL] Kernel behaviour on panic: delay <timeout>
>                 timeout > 0: seconds before rebooting
>                 timeout = 0: wait forever
>                 timeout < 0: reboot immediately
>                 Format: <timeout>
> ```

**links**

- [source code](https://salsa.debian.org/kernel-team/initramfs-tools/-/blob/cf964bfb4362019fd7fba1e839e403ff950dca8e/scripts/functions#L46)
- [Securing Debian Manual - Disable root prompt on the initramfs](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-manual/kernel-initramfs-prompt.en.html)

Comment: Oh! That's the same one as the kernel. But you want to set it to something non zero.  Setting it to zero explicitly says don't reboot: https://salsa.debian.org/kernel-team/initramfs-tools/-/blob/cf964bfb4362019fd7fba1e839e403ff950dca8e/scripts/functions#L55

Comment: If initramfs fails, it fails! You can not boot a system with e.g. missing root disk. All you can do is to reboot in loop and hope the problem disappears.

Comment: @PhilipCouling thanks for the additional info

Answer (score -1):

On failure during startup (e.g. mounting device) the system starts into "emergency.target" and starts "emergency.service".
The message "(or type Control-D for normal startup)" is shown at this point.

```
# systemctl status emergency.service 
○ emergency.service - Emergency Shell
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/emergency.service; static)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:sulogin(8)
```

This starts the root-login shell by asking for root password (see `man 8 sulogin`).

Just mask the service and the target and it can not be started. But I have no experience what happens if a serious error occurs where the system can not be started. Be careful, better test it somehow.

```
sudo systemctl mask emergency.service
sudo systemctl mask emergency.target
```

Comment: Either I've missed something fundamental here or you have. You seem to be describing things to change in the root filesystem. I'm asking about [initramfs](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/initramfs.html) which contains scripts that are executed before the root file system is mounted. Are you saying that ubuntu uses systemd inside initramfs?

Comment: I inspected the initramfs of a 23.04 VM and it doesn't seem to contain systemd itself (a couple of config files, but I think  nothing that might help).

Comment: @PhilipCouling if initramfs fails, the error is that serious, that the system does not boot (half broken disk, root can not be mounted, etc...). I updated the answer to make clear, to which "message" my answer is.

Comment: No that's not true. The [grub environment block](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Environment-block.html) allows the boot loader to keep track of what it has tried to reboot.  A well designed configuration can detect failed boots and rollback to a previously working configuration.  This massively reduces the risk of of system upgrades bricking an unattended device located 100s of miles from a human being.